# Selenium gets stuck during alert Python

Tags: python, selenium

I've encountered a problem with selenium + chrome-driver.

URL that I am working with: https://tixcraft.com/ticket/verify/23_ttp6th/12494
What I want to do is to accept the error alert when I intentionally send the wrong key. However, the code always gets stuck unless I manually accept it.

```
        veri_box = self.std_wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'checkCode'))
        )
        veri_box.send_keys("randomKey")
        veri_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        #the code gets stuck here unless I manually click OK on the alert.        
        self.std_wait.until(EC.alert_is_present()).accept()
```

Any idea what could be the issue?
Thanks?

I've tried manually keying random values in the input box and press Enter. The code detects the alert successfully that way.

I expect using Selenium to key in the values would be the same but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, self.std_wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the alert box is outside of the web element whereby you need to switch the focus before `accept()` or `dismiss()` it.

You can achieve it by doing so :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert_box = driver.switch_to.alert
alert_box.dismiss()
```

You can read more about it [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#popup-dialogs)